# Meaning of "near-atomic" transfer using temporary files?

Tags: scp, temporary-files

I was reading 'SCP' command man page in linux, in the end it said

> "No attempt is made at "near-atomic" transfer using temporary files".

Vaguely I can guess what it is but can anyone clearly tell me the technical definition of this sentence.

Thanks,
paddy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atomic would mean that nothing else could read or write the file until scp had finished with it. "Near-atomic" refers to the common practise of *copying* a file into a temporary location (on the target machine/disk) and then *moving* it into the final location. The move operation is much faster than a copy ("near-atomic" by comparison) but it's not necessarily atomic in the true sense of the word. Another process could still read the file in an inconsistent state during a non-atomic move.

Comment: The point about moves being only near-atomic is not necessarily correct. At least on Linux moves are guaranteed to be atomic, as long as target and destination are on the same partition. In that case a move is only a change in the metadata, so that the full file appears at once at the destination. See also the other answer below.

Comment: @LiKao I said "...but it's not **necessarily** atomic...". As in not *guaranteed* to be in every scenario and configuration where `scp` might be used. So what is "not necessarily correct" about my answer?

Comment: To try rephrasing the improvement that @LiKao might have been trying to get at: It would be clearer to distinguish two cases. Moves on the same partition are instant and atomic, since `rename()` is called to point the name to a new inode, which already contains the full content of the file. Moves between partitions mean copying the file content gradually, which is not atomic. The phrase “much faster” seems a bit vague, when under the right conditions it is not only faster but instantaneous.

Answer (score 7):

An atomic copy would be as Craig states, to use a temporary file and then mv the temporary file to the intended destination. The mv IS an atomic providing source and destination are on the same partition. Only file operations with the tmp file open already will be able to read the contents. rename() is not atomic on files that move between partitions as the data has to be copied.

This assumes you're scp'ing to a UNIX system of course :)